# External monitors via USB-C dock not recognized until I restart computer

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, display, dell, external-monitor

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS on a Dell Latitude 3520 laptop, which is connected to two external monitors via a Dell USB-C dock. This works great, except when I suspend the laptop and disconnect the dock for the weekend, and then come back and re-connect the dock, the external monitors are no longer recognized, and neither is the ethernet cable (also connected to the dock), but my mouse and keyboard *are* recognized (also connected to the dock).

Reviewing the output of `lsusb`, I can see that the dock itself is recognized, but I don't see any change in the output when I disconnect the external monitors from the dock.

I see only the builtin display listed under Settings > Displays and in the output of `xrandr`.

The only fix that I've found is to restart my computer (logging out and in may also work, though I haven't tried that yet).

Is there a way to "reset" my connection with the USB-C dock and/or the ethernet cable and/or the external monitors, without restarting my computer?

Comment: Sometimes, Ubuntu does not recognize new devices after a kernel upgrade, unless the system is restarted. Just to ensure that it is not the case here, if you suspend, and resume immediately, does the issue occur?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I just tested this. If I suspend and resume immediately, without disconnecting the dock, the problem does not occur. However, if I suspend, disconnect the dock, reconnect the dock, and resume, then the problem does occur.

Comment: @jth, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @Ofiris Yes, I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have been solved. I believe I flashed a firmware upgrade to the dock (from a different laptop running Pop!_OS) at some point recently, and I also upgraded my Dell laptop to Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. So either of those upgrades may have helped solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue on debian.  Had to delete ~/.config/monitors.xml, then logout.

Now I can just plug my hub in anytime, and monitors work right away without issues.  Hope this works for you too.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'll remember to try this if the issue re-appears.